# DNS domain redemption policy

Tags: dns, domain-registration

I want to know if my registrar could have done what I expected, and if they could still fix the mistake. See QUESTIONS below.

I intentionally deleted a domain name with my host/registar, because I wanted to re-start the site someplace with better services. (They claimed to offer a "Change of provider" option when cancelling, but it actually didn't exist as advertised.) The [cancellation form](http://faq.1and1.com/image/domains/cancel8.png) told me it would be immediately available for registration by other parties when deleted.

Now, a few days after the listed date of cancellation, I got a reply from support explaining the reason the domain is not available is because it has entered a redemption period.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Could the host/registrar have immediately deleted the domain as I expected?
2. Can the host/registrar 'finalize' the deletion now to release it?
3. Can they authorize a transfer at this point?

---

Side note: I think 1and1.com is a registrar, right? So they failed to meet registrar requirements I found when researching redemption. ["3.7.5.5 If Registrar operates a website for domain name registration or renewal, details of Registrar's deletion and auto-renewal policies must be clearly displayed on the website."](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/accreditation/eddp) I think the errors in the page I linked show this was not done. I suppose this might give me some leverage with support.

Comment: You are presumably wanting to _transfer_ the domain to a different registrar? Why did you "delete" it?! What's the TLD?

Comment: Their "transfer" option was not where it was supposed to be. I deleted it because it seemed it would be more expedient and equally effective, according to the information they posted.

It is a .com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Mistake:** You deleted the domain.

**Their Mistake:** They imply that the domain is instantly available after cancellation which is simply untrue with most TLD and CCTLD domains as it enters an redemption period.

**Transferring Domains do not need canceling**

You should never cancel your domain if you are unhappy with an registrar if you wish to keep that domain, you should of have had transferred with it to another company without deleting and can only assume that you read their incorrect cancellation form rather than the [1and1 Transfer FAQ](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_xfers/xfer_of_reg/index.html)

**Good News**

You shouldn't get hang up on whose fault this is and if you really want your domain back then this should be your primary focus. Now the good news is when domains enter redemption periods they are ***REDEEMABLE*** by the owner of that domain and normally on average this period lasts from 30-40 days depending on the TLD [**type of the domain**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name). So haven't lost your domain as of yet.

Now as I said domains are savable even when they enter the redemption period the problem you face now is charges that they will place on top of renewing the domain. So you will need to pay "1 Year + Redemption Charges" since you have not included what TLD type this I can't tell you for sure but on 1and1 website it says [.com .net .org redemption fee of £25](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_admin/2.html)

**Best Way to Proceed**

This is based on opinion but you should ring them as soon as possible explain them what has occurred and tell them you want your domain back. When they mention the charges point out that the website contains conflicting information and you would not be in this position if they contained the full facts on the situation.

You should tell them and ask if:

- You will pay the renewal cost (As you intended anyway - of buying it new)
- Ask for **Goodwill** if they could cancel the additional costs since to the wrong information on their site.
- Ask them about transferring your domain once you have renewed it or read the FAQ that I linked too.

Comment: Thank you. I'm equally interested in knowing the new registration underpinnings that caused this mess, since the last domain I cancelled was years ago. I assume the answers for 1, 2, and 3 were all "no"?

Answer (score 3):

bybe's answer is essentially correct. This is just to supplement it with specific info you requested:

1. ICANN's [*Registrar Accreditation Agreement*](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/raa/ra-agreement-21may09-en.htm) seems to imply that registrars should implement a 45-day auto-renewal grace period, but I don't see a formal requirement to do so. And it explicitly allows registrars to delete a domain prior to the end of the grace period. The only requirement on registrars is that they delete the domain *within 10 days after the auto-renewal grace period expires*, and that they clearly publish their auto-renewal grace period policy.

   However, **there is a separate, post-deletion *Redemption Grace Period*, which would likely be enforced by the registry not the registrar**. This is what's preventing the domain from being freshly registered.

   If you want to understand why these grace periods are in place, this was originally proposed in the [*Redemption Grace Period For Deleted Names* discussion paper](http://archive.icann.org/en/registrars/redemption-proposal-14feb02.htm) back in 2002 as a response to the high number of accidental/fraudulent domain deletions by registrars/registrants and domain-name hijackers. But it seems that many registrars have been [exploiting this rule for their own advantage](http://www.sitepoint.com/period-farce-exposed/) by charging exorbitant recovery fees (the £25 fee bybe cites for 1and1 is actually quite low; many registrars charge upwards of $100 to even $200).
2. If the issue were the domain being held in the auto-renewal grace period, then, yes, the registrar could go ahead and delete the domain immediately. But as mentioned above, your domain has already been deleted and is in the *Domain Name Redemption Grace Period*. The registrar now has no control of the domain unless you choose to redeem the domain and reclaim ownership over it. Beyond that, **the TLD registry that manages the domain is in control of its status**, and their policy is likely to adhere to ICANN's 30-day redemption grace period (which applies to all unsponsored TLDs, such as .com, .net, .org, .biz, .info, and .name).
3. No, not unless you reclaim your domain one way or another. They are however the only registrar that you can reclaim the domain with [according to the ICANN FAQs page](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/compliance/faqs).